# Screen tint/filter software?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen, colors

I'm trying to find any kind of software that allows you to change the tint of your screen. I've seen redshift and f.lux, but they're not exactly what I'm looking for - both of them shift with the time of day and only offer a red colouration, whereas I'm looking for something that holds the colour permanently and which has a wide variety of colours.

A Windows example of what I'm looking for is [ScreenRuler](https://www.clarosoftware.com/screenruler), from the ClaroRead software bundle.

Is there anything like that that exists for linux?

Comment: Are you aware of the cli options of redshift? specifically the -o option would be interesting. from `man redshift`:         `-o     One shot mode (do not continuously adjust color temperature)` and: `-O TEMP One shot manual mode (set color temperature)` Seems exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I am aware of the cli options - as far as I'm aware, it unfortunately doesn't give me the variety of colour I'm looking for.